# Transform matrix without loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have `oldMat` which is a ranking of equity tickers. The column number represents the respective rank, e.g. first column equals highest rank, second column represents second highest rank and so on. The integers within `oldMat`represent the number of the individual equity ticker. The number `3` in `oldMat(3,2,1)`means, that the third equity ticker is ranked second in the third period (rows represent different periods).

Now, I need to transform `oldMat` in the following way: The column numbers now represent the individual equity tickers. The integers now represent the rank that individual equity tickers hold at specific periods. For example, the number `2` in `newMat(3,3,1)` means, that the third equity ticker is ranked second in the third period.

I used a for-loop in order to solve that problem, but I am pretty sure there exists a more efficient way to achieve this result. Here's my code:

```
% Define oldMat
oldMat(:,:,1) = ...
    [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN; ...
    1, 3, 4, 6, 2, 5; ...
    6, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5; ...
    2, 3, 6, 1, 4, 5; ...
    5, 4, 6, 2, 3, 1; ...
    5, 1, 2, 3, 6, 4; ...
    4, 5, 1, 3, 6, 2; ...
    4, 1, 6, 5, 2, 3];
oldMat(:,:,2) = ...
    [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN; ...
    NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN; ...
    1, 6, 3, 4, 2, 5; ...
    6, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5; ...
    2, 6, 3, 4, 1, 5; ...
    5, 2, 1, 6, 3, 4; ...
    5, 1, 3, 6, 2, 4; ...
    4, 1, 5, 6, 3, 2];

% Pre-allocate newMat
newMat = nan(size(oldMat));

% Transform oldMat to newMat
for runNum = 1 : size(newMat,3)

    for colNum = 1 : size(newMat,2)

        for rowNum = 1 : size(newMat,1)
            if ~isnan(oldMat(rowNum, colNum, runNum))
                newMat(rowNum,oldMat(rowNum, colNum, runNum), runNum) = colNum;
            end
        end

    end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a classic case of [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html).  You want to create a set of linear indices to access the second dimension of the new matrix and set those equal to the column number.  First create a grid of 3D coordinates with [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html), then use the `oldMat` matrix as an index into the second column of the output and set this equal to the column number.  Make sure that you don't copy over any `NaN` values or `sub2ind` will complain.  You can use [`isnan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html) to help filter these values out for you:

```
% Initialize new matrix
newMat = nan(size(oldMat));

% Generate a grid of coordinates
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(1:size(newMat,2), 1:size(newMat,1), 1:size(newMat,3));

% Find elements that are NaN and remove
mask = isnan(oldMat);
X(mask) = []; Y(mask) = []; Z(mask) = [];

% Set the values now
newMat(sub2ind(size(oldMat), Y, oldMat(~isnan(oldMat)).', Z)) = X;
```